# pandas dataframe to csv, format problem about string of numbers

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a dataframe df, where the first column stores strings like '000001', '000002', '000003'... ect. they are keys of the dataframe with the necessary 0s in front.

when I try to save df to csv file and call df.to_csv(), the column is saved as 1, 2, 3... instead of the raw data as '000001', '000002'.

Can I solve this problem when saving data to csv file from pandas dataframe?

for example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.normal(0, 1, (3, 3)))
df.iloc[:, 0] = ['0001', '0002', '0003']
print(df)

df.to_csv('somedata.csv', index=False)

#then read back or directly open (mine is with excel)
df = pd.read_csv('somedata.csv')
print(df)
```

values in column 0 are 1, 2, 3

Comment: Maybe you mean `df.to_csv(index=False)`?

Comment: @Ynjxsjmh, values are saved in the first column, not as index

Comment: " the column is saved as 1, 2, 3... instead of the raw data as '000001', '000002'." can you please provide a [mcve]? If I test this out, `df = pd.DataFrame(dict(col=['000001', '000002', '000003']))` then use `print(df.to_csv())` I do not get the output you say you do.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, I have found the reason! it's because I open the output csv file with excel.

Answer (score 0):

Solution: the file is 00001, 00002. when open with excel, it display as 1, 2, 3. if using pd.read_csv(), one need to specify dtype=str